# Could the CF (15 million) and IOG (3 million) funds be split between more small pools?

Tags: stake-pool, staking, cardano-foundation

There are a lot of small pools out there that find it hard to get the minimum stake to ensure at least one block per epoch.

As you may know, CF and IOG have rounds of funding every three months: CF delegates 15 million ADA and IOG 3 million.
The minimum amount of stake to get one block per epoch is about 1 million ADA.

So my question is, will CF or IOG ever consider delegating just one million to many more pools, thus helping more pools achieve their social goals?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about the future of Cardano can't be effectively addressed on this site and would be better addressed directly to the Cardano Team on their [forum](https://forum.cardano.org/). This site is not operated by the Cardano organization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they could.

I think this question should be directed to these parties.

Comment: Yes, that question should not be posted on SE. Voted for closing it.